# Running OOZIE java client with SSL from a machine which is not part of hadoop cluster/edgenode

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, oozie

I am trying to trigger an oozie workflow from the java client which runs on a machine which is not part of hadoop cluster.

Ozzie installation on the cluster has SSL configured, and when I run my Oozie java client on the remote machine(Not part of cluster or edgenode) I get the below error

```
  IO_ERROR : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I try the same code on edgenode(part of the hadoop cluster) the code runs successfully.

Can I get the details on how to run Oozie client from remote machine and how can I resolve certificate/authorization issue ?

Note: I have tried setting the certificate conf in the code and that does not work for me.

Hadoop Cluster has Cloudera

MIK

Comment: On the Edge Node, either the default "truststore" for the Java install lists the appropriate certification chain _(i.e. the root CA, then the intermediate CAs up to the one that signed the SSL certificates on the cluster)_, or the env variable `HADOOP_OPTS` is set with Java properties that point to a custom "truststore"

Comment: That's a generic Java/SSL issue, not a Hadoop/Oozie issue. Contact your Hadoop admins to get instructions.